# user.uid.501.BRNotificationServerAvailabilityChanges error in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, icloud, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

I am executing this code to get files/document from iCloud

```
NSMetadataQuery *metadataQuery = [[NSMetadataQuery alloc] init];
[metadataQuery setSearchScopes:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:
      NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]];

[metadataQuery setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE 'myfile.zip'", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey]];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(metadataQueryDidFinishGathering:)
     name:NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification
     object:metadataQuery];

 if (![metadataQuery startQuery]) {
        NSLog(@"Start query not work for some reason.");
 }
```

I am getting this error

```
 [default] [ERROR] notify_get_state(241) failed with 'invalid_token' (2) for 'user.uid.501.BRNotificationServerAvailabilityChanges'
```

Due to this error, it doesn't fire

> NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGatheringNotification

NotificationCenter.

Anyone face any such issue before.

Comment: Are you separating this query search in another stand alone class and calling it from where the search is supposed to happen in the ViewController?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue and figured out what went wrong.
The error basically means that the `NSMetadataQuery` variable was deallocated on function completion before it actually finishes gathering information. You can solve by declaring the metadata query as a property for a class.

```swift
class UbiquitousFileManager {
    private var metadata: NSMetadataQuery?
    
    func retrieve() {
        self.metadata = NSMetadataQuery()
        self.metadata!.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K like %@", NSMetadataItemFSNameKey, "somefile.txt")
        self.metadata!.searchScopes = [NSMetadataQueryUbiquitousDocumentsScope]

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: .NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering,
            object: self.metadata!,
            queue: nil,
            using: { notification in
                // Do something with the result...
         })

        self.metadata!.start()
    }
}
```

Also do not forget to keep the manager instance as a property for the `UIViewController` etc.

```swift
final class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    private let manager = UbiquitousFileManager()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem.

What I eventually figured out is, that if I run the code in a stand alone class, even if derived from NSObject, I will get that error.

As soon as I move the code into a UIViewController class, it works.

No idea still what the reason is, though.

Comment: Hey, could you please provide some more details about what happened, and how you fixed it? Which code exactly needs to run within a UIViewController?  I just encountered this from a class (not derived from NSObject), and moved the Notification Handling code to a UIViewController, and am still getting this. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not have that code any longer because some design changes made it obsolete. But if I remember correctly I put the complete query inside a UIViewController instance, not only the Notification handling.